# android how to terminate functionand return to asyntask after getting spesific value

Tags: android

how to terminate function at spesific point i use break but its not work help me please i want when current date match with database not procesing further and function close break is not working nay other advice?????

```
                public class getDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    getDataTask() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         yourBoolean=false;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        displayData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        yourBoolean=true ;
        listCategory.setAdapter(cla);
        menu_nametxt.setText(mVal2);
                                  }








                    private void displayData() {


    Cursor mCursor2 =  db.selectQuery("SELECT s.name ASxxxx ORDER BY md.sort ASC");


    if (mCursor2.moveToFirst()) {
        do {



        Calendar_id =(mCursor2.getString(mCursor2.getColumnIndex("calendar_id")));


        } while (mCursor2.moveToNext());
    }


    mCursor2.close();






 Cursor mCursor3 =  db.selectQuery("SELECT * FROM uss_vacation WHERE calendar_id = 
      '"+Calendar_id+"' ");


    if (mCursor3.moveToFirst()) {
        do {


  Vacation_Date.add(mCursor3.getString(mCursor3.getColumnIndex("date")));

    if(mCursor3.getString(mCursor3.getColumnIndex("date")).equals(mydate))
            {
           String  mVal  ;
                mVal = 
  (mCursor3.getString(mCursor3.getColumnIndex("title")));

        //
                mVal3 = mVal;

  //////////////////////////////help here//////////////////////
 i want function displayData(); close at this like and not processing further any idea?? i used 
    break but is not work
                break;

            }


        } while (mCursor3.moveToNext());
    }


    mCursor3.close();








Cursor mCursor =  db.selectQuery("SELECT s.name  '"+Meal_groupid+"' ORDER BY md.sort ASC");
    Category_ID.clear();
    school_name.clear();
    menu_name.clear();

    dish_name.clear();
    dish_ID.clear();
    day.clear();



    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            zero1check = valll.toString();
            if (zero1check.equals("0"))
                byweekdate = Todayday + 1;
            else if (zero1check.equals("1")) {
                byweekdate = Todayday + 2;

            }

      school_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("school_name")));
            String Scdedulechk;

            Scdedulechk=(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("Schedule")));
            Schedule.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("Schedule")));
            day.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("day")));

            String chkdate;

            chkdate=(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("day")));


            if ((Scdedulechk).equals("weekly")) {

                if ((chkdate).equals(Todayday)) {




       menu_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("menu_title")));
            String menu_title;

            menu_title=
      (mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("menu_title")));
            mVal2=menu_title.toString();


   dish_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("dish_name")));

dish_ID.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("dish_id")));



   Category_ID.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("calendar_id")));
                }
            }
            else 
                if ((Scdedulechk).equals("biweekly")) {

                    if ((chkdate).equals(byweekdate)) {




   menu_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("menu_title")));


   dish_name.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("dish_name")));


     dish_ID.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("dish_id")));



    Category_ID.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("calendar_id")));
                    }
                }


        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }


    mCursor.close();


}
```

Comment: I'm going to just be honest here, and point out that your code is disgusting.  Skill or no skill, there's no sense in code that sloppy.

Comment: Please format your code properly, especially the braces, it is impossible to follow.  Please also explain what "didn't work" means.

Comment: Please, if you ask any questions in the future, please take the time to format your code properly (e.g. make sure the indentation is correct) and only include relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `break` with `return`. `break` just breaks the loop, `return` "stops" the method.

Comment: Great, we're now teaching Java fundamentals at SO.

Comment: Well, that's my best guess. I actually don't want to read the whole horrible code above.

Comment: I'm not knocking your answer - I'm annoyed by the overwhelming number of questions like this one that simply lack fundamentals.

Answer (score 0):

Change you function's return type from void to int or else and return any thing when your desired action completed.
for eg.

```
int test_func(){ 

 //your code here
if(actionCompleted){
    return 1;
// function will be closed 
 }
else
//your code

return 0;
}
```